# Firebase cloud function is not triggered on user deletion

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've created a firebase cloud function to be triggered on user deletion, as mentioned in the firebase documentation:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firestore = admin.firestore();
admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUserData = functions.auth.user().onDelete((event) => {
  const uid = event.uid;
  const firestorePromise = clearFirestoreData(uid);

  return Promise.all([firestorePromise])
      .then(() => console.log(`Successfully removed data for user #${uid}.`)
  );
});
```

After deleting the user from my iOS application, by calling:

```
user.reauthenticate(with: credential) { result, error in
    if let error = error {
        completion(error)
    } else {
        user.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                completion(error)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In firebase, the user is deleted from "Authentication", but the function is not triggered.

If I delete the user directly from "Authentication" in the firebase console, the function is triggered and deletes the user's data successfully.

I am using:

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have reported the same issue.  See the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/ROXTbooVzlM/vY1kh9TqAQAJ).

This seems like a bug with the Cloud Functions.  If that's the case, then there's nothing Stack Overflow can help with.

I will encourage you to [file a bug report directly with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) so they can collect data and escalate to engineering.